# "He's dead, Jim!" each 5 minutes in Chromium

Tags: chromium

Please tell what happened, this didn't happened when I had Debian

[image]

Actually, I have 512MB RAM so I changed my swappiness to 90% is this because of that?
EDIT: CHANGED BACK TO 60% BUT NOTHING HAPPENED, SAME PROBLEM

Comment: Can you start `chromium-browser` from a terminal, save its output, and post it here? It may contain useful information.

Comment: Try this from terminal `chromium-browser --incognito`. Does it work?

Comment: @Mitch i know its incognito but, it does not stores passwords, thats the problem!

Comment: @DavidFoerster no i will not do it as, when i will post it here, it will leave some sensitive data for you!

Comment: @Braiam no i dont think its  a bug

Comment: no dude this happenes since i installed it and it works fine on a live USB

Comment: @Braiam actually, i have 512 mb ram so i changed my swappiness to 90% is this because of that?

Comment: okay i updated but what to do now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Try reseting your profile:

1. Exit chromium completely.
2. Go to Computer.
3. Select Go > Location.
4. Enter the following directory in the text field:

   ```
    ~/.config/google-chrome/
   ```
5. Locate the folder called "Default" in the directory window that opens and rename it as "Backup default."
6. Try opening Google Chrome again. A new "Default" folder is automatically created as you start using the browser.

---

If you wish, you can transfer information from your old user profile to your new one.
However, this action is not recommended, since a part of your old profile may be corrupt.

With that in mind, to transfer your old bookmarks, copy the `Bookmarks.bak` file from the **Backup default** folder to your new **Default** folder. Once moved, rename the file from `Bookmarks.bak` to `Bookmarks` to complete the migration.

All other browser data will remain in the **Backup default** folder, but you won't be able to transfer it to your new profile.

Answer (score 3):

> actually, i have 512 mb ram so i changed my swappiness to 90% is this because of that?

You need more RAM. Chrome can exhaust memory pretty quick, if you don't have available the child's dies and you get the "He's dead Jim!" screen. Also, a 60% of swappiness should be fine, there is actually no need to change the swappiness unless you have process that merit that action.

Change the swappiness back, add more memory and clear your cache and cookies. That should solve your problem.

(if it works in a live system, you should consider what are the differences between each, like programs opened, configurations that are not defaults, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the this problem then I realized that the problem was the chrome version that I had installed.
And my problem was resolved by installing the latest version of Chrome.
**I would recommend you to use Chrome instead of Chromium.**

To install latest Google Chrome in Ubuntu open Terminal (Press Ctrl+Alt+T) and copy the following commands in the Terminal:

For 32-bit
Terminal Commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3 libnspr4-0d libxss1
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*; rm google-chrome*
```

For 64-bit
Terminal Commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3 libnspr4-0d libxss1
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*; rm google-chrome*
```

Comment: `utkarsh@utkarsh-MS-7267:~$ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*
[sudo] password for utkarsh: 
dpkg: error processing google-chrome* (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome*
utkarsh@utkarsh-MS-7267:~$ 
`

Comment: this is a wrong command!

Comment: If by this code, you can not get Chrome to install, go to the following URL:
https://www.google.com/intl/en/chrome/browser/?platform=linux
Click on Download and select Ubuntu from there. (32-bit or 64-bit)
It gives you a Debian file. That you can easily install it.

Comment: @Utkarsh how about you edit your question and add what happens when you execute MHN commands.